# AngularJS ui-grid 3.x filter on empty value

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

For an AngularJS ui-grid 3.x I defined a filter object to filter on empty values:

```
           $scope.gridOptions = {
            enableFiltering: true,
            columnDefs: [ 
                { field: 'assignedto',
                  name: 'Assigned To',
                  width: 250,
                  filter: ... the filter object ..
                }]
```

The filter object looks like this:

```
                    {
                    filter: {
                        type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT,
                        selectOptions: [{ value: 1, label: 'Defined' },
                                        { value: 2, label: '(Blanks)' }],
                        condition: function (searchTerm, cellValue) {
                            return
                            searchTerm == 0 ||
                            searchTerm == null ||
                            (searchTerm == 1 && cellValue != null) ||
                            (searchTerm == 2 && cellValue == null)
                        }
                    }
```

This filter object gives a dropbox. Using the drop box, rows should be filtered containing empty values. However the filter does not work and I think it has to do with the condition not set up correctly. How to set this up to make it working?

Some initial data, I want to filter the rows containing an empty value for column 'assignedto':

```
           $scope.gridOptions = {                
             data: [
                { assignedto: 'James' },
                { assignedto: 'Nicole' },
                { assignedto: '' },
                { assignedto: 'James' },
                { assignedto: 'Nicole' },
                { assignedto: '' }
            ]
        };
```